# Is there a way to do equally spaces for Yaxis when y axis scales are of different values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

class plottingCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(plottingCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
        fig.tight_layout()

canvas = plottingCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
    

canvas.axes.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--')
ylabel = np.array([0.000002, 0.00001, 0.00002, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2])
canvas.axes.yaxis.set_ticks(ylabel)
ticker = matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter(unit='V')
canvas.axes.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker)
canvas.axes.set_ylim(ymin=0.000002, ymax=0.200)
canvas.draw()
```

Above is the code where y axis indicate the voltage values which range from uV to mV . With the above I'm getting the plot as below:

[image]

I even tried with below code but no luck .

```
canvas.axes.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(ylabel))
canvas.axes.yaxis.set_set_ticklabels(ylabel)
```

Can someone help in getting equally spaced y axis scale.

Thanks.

[image]

Expecting the equally spaced y axis scale as show in the above figure.

Comment: You say you want equally spaced, then go on to give an example that isn't equally spaced. It has to have a consistent measure - if you are including uV, your scale has to be in uV, not mixing uV and mV. It also cannot go from 2 uV to 1 uV to 20 uV (2nd image). Also be wary of how busy the chart will be unless you want a giant image.

Comment: @Alan,  My bad, its typo in my second image ( 2uV, 10uV, 20uV, 100uV, 200UV, etc up to 200mv) . I don't mind if the chart is busy  plotting it . Also , plotting will vary from 2uV to 200mV. IT won't go beyond the above mentioned values.

Comment: @Alan , I have added new image

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You are setting the ylabel when you should be setting yticks.

Your new image is still inconsistent (unless you are using a log scale or similar). You can't have 2uV -> 10uV etc., you would need to have 2 uV -> 4 uV etc.

There are also two errors in the code you gave:

`canvas = plottingCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)` should not include `self`.
`ticker = matplotlib.ticker.EngFormatter(unit='V')` should not include `matplotlib` as you have used `import matplotlib.ticker as ticker`.

I'm not familiar with the `backend_qt5agg`, I'll give an example below using the regular plot and it should translate across directly.

Assuming plot values are x and y, where x is a series and y is a series, and the third value is the step value.

`yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, 3.0))`

Note: The min and max values can be set manually. For example, if you like having 200 uV as the ceiling, then:

`yticks(np.arange(0, 201, 1.0))`

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = ["one", "two", three]
y = np.array([0.000002, 0.00001, 0.00002, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2])
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('uV')
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, 0.1))
plt.savefig('measurements.png')
```

Given the wide array of values in the example - min of 0.000002 and max of 0.2 - it would make some sense to round out the values. When comparing to 0.2 or 0.05, is there any difference between 0.000002 and 0.00001? They may be functionally zero.